# radio button onclick in bootstrap issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use onclick even with radio butttons in bootstrap but the onclick event is not firing. i am using this code

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="alert('Scenery!')"/>
```

But when i use

```
 <label class="" onclick="alert('Scenery!')">
            <input type="checkbox" id="scenery-option" onclick="alert('Scenery!')"/> 
        </label>
```

But when i use above code and click on label its working but on radio button its not working

Comment: Please try to reproduce the problem through code snippet in the question..

Comment: There should be another problem in your code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZoNXzY

Comment: It is working  - https://jsfiddle.net/6juk2xwk/1/. But triggering twice for checkbox and label. Remove the onclick from input element.

Comment: in bootstrap its not working.

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery. So you could solve it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#scenery-option', function(){
 alert('works');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all** you wrote in title *radio button* but in example you show us `checkbox`.

So is it a problem with `radio` or `checkbox`?

**Secondly**

Your problem can't be reproduced. Look at an example below. When you click `checkbox` alert shows twice. One for label and one for checkbox.
I changed alert message so that you can see the difference

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label class="" onclick="alert('Label clicked!')">
  Here is some text:
  <input type="checkbox" id="scenery-option" onclick="alert('Checkbox clicked!')"/> 
</label>
```

**Additionally**

In case of `radio` and `checkbox` buttons I reccomend using [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event which fires when elements value changes.

```js
$("#scenery-option").on('change', function() {
  alert("Checkbox value changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label>
  Here is some text:
  <input type="checkbox" id="scenery-option" /> 
</label>
```